# Quality Checks on Excel / Automation

Tags: automated-testing, quality-assurance, excel, data-analysis, data

I am tasked to complete a quality check on excel.
Background - We receive several excel files from different vendors daily. Before putting on the BI tool i need to make sure the naming convention is matching what is in Power BI and check 4-5 columns to see if they are accurately populated. Sometime the rows in few columns are empty and they are populated by hyphens with space leading and trailing it (  -  ).

Currently i am updating this manually. Is there a faster way to do this? Check the files to see the naming is correct and the columns have consistent data type.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, there is a way. But you are actually paid for finding that solution, so it's better if you suggest something and show us so we can suggest improvements or help you when you get stuck on something. But people here won't solve the whole problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have a similar job; pulling down reports from different vendors in Excel and doing a pseudo-ETL. [Excel Macros](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office) were great and I had one macro for each vendor. Still, I saved countless hours each week by learning macros.